# Code not executing in Ionic after a post method

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, authentication

I have posted to my API and everything is working (getting the network class etc). However after I call the method the rest of the code is not executing.

```
Login.ts 

login() {
    this.authService.login(this.email, this.pw).subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        console.log('Working');
        this.presentLoading();
        // store jwt
        // move to dashboard
        console.log('Valid User');
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/menu/first/tabs/tab1');
        this.router.navigate(['/menu/first']);
          }
      },  error => {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            console.log('Authorisation Required');
          }
        }
      );
  }


auth-service.ts

login(email, pw) {
  if (email === '' || pw === '') {
    this.presentAlert();
  } else {
  const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('email', email)
  .set('pw', pw);
  return this.http.post<any>(apiUrl + 'login', {email, pw}, {params});
  }
}
```

Comment: post your auth service

Comment: Edited with auth-service

Comment: which http are you using native or angular?

Comment: are u ending your apiurl with / ?

Comment: Im using HTTPClient from @angular/common/http. And yes the api ends with a /

Comment: i have posted an answer try it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
login(email, pw) {

  return this.http.get(apiUrl + "login?"+"email="+email+"pw="+pw)
         .map(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

**validate** email and password in **login.ts**

Comment: No still not working unfortunately. http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/action/action.php/login is coming up so it is not getting the input values

Comment: u tried in postman or some other service to check whether api is working?

Comment: Yea it works in Postman when using parameters to get email and password perfectly

Comment: http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/action/action.php/login?email=test@email.com&pw=password

Comment: that is a get request

Comment: Ah my bad. So i need to remove the params and put the username/pw inside a body then?